# What is the proper name used to describe stuff like class, namespace, fields, etc... in programming languages?

Tags: computer-science

This might sound like a strange question but I was thinking about the name used to describe stuff like classes, namespaces, fields, etc... in programming languages?

like if you have a dog, a cat and a cow you can say that you have some `animals` right?

what about if you have a class a namespace and a field how do you describe them?

I have already done some research but couldn't find anything useful till now...

thanks in advance.

Comment: "Programming constructs" perhaps?

Comment: So when I have some classes or some namespaces I can say that I have a set of programming constructs?